# Why does Object debugger say my URL is a facebook URL and isn't "scrapable"

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api

In trying to create an "object" page for my first facebook app, I've run into some difficulty.  I followed [Facebook's Open Graph Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/) nearly exactly.

After creating an "object" html page with the appropriate `<meta property="og:...` tags I tried running the URL through the [Debugger Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) as suggested in the tutorial but I'm given the following error:

"**Facebook URLs aren't scrapable by this Debugger. Try your own.**"

This page is in the same directory on my company's linux box as the canvas page, and is certainly *not* a "Facebook URL".  If it matters, I'm using an IP instead of a domain name: `xx.x.x.xxx/app/obj.html`

...

I continued the tutorial anyway, but ultimately it does not seem to want to post a new `action/object` (*is this even right*?).  I did however manage to get *something* to work, as in the `app timeline view` I apparently `actioned` one of those `objects` a couple hours ago.  I assume this happened when I was pasting `curl POST` commands into the terminal.

I'm pretty new to the whole open graph, and facebook APIs, etc., so I'm probably operating under false assumptions of some sort, and I've been all over trying different things, but this error seems pretty bizarre to me and I can't seem to resolve it.

**UPDATE**

I just took the object page and put it on my own personal shared hosting acct.  The debugger worked (inexplicably) fine on it, but I couldn't go too far since it's a different domain than the one authorized by my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `og:url` inside your html page does not point to facebook.

Also, make sure to look at the [open graph protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) page (to see you formatted the og tags correctly.

Also, make sure the page is accessible to everyone, not just yourself.

Comment: Is the url accessible from all, or blocked by firewall ?

Comment: I can see its contents fine just pasting the url into the address bar

Comment: My question was not if you can access it, but if anyone else can... maybe Facebook servers can't reach the page for some reason, and you see this error.

Comment: hmmm, interesting - one minute

Comment: I think you might have it right. Seems obvious in retrospect.  If you'd like to update your answer to suggest the firewall thing I'll give you a check mark

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the URL it's hard to be sure, but it's most likely that your URL is either including a `og:url` tag pointing to a facebook.com address, or a HTTP 301/302 redirect to Facebook instead

Comment: the only place fb urls appear in this file is in the `html` and `head` attributes: `<html ... xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"><head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# ssiz-three:                http://ogp.me/ns/apps/ssiz-three#">`

Comment: And when you make a request manually from the internet using curl with the user agent header `facebookexternalhit/1.1` your page is returning valid markup without a redirect to facebook.com, an `og:url` tag pointing to facebook.com or a `<link rel="canonical"...` pointing there either?

Comment: Hey Igy, thanks for trying to help.  Yes it is, but its all sorted out now ;-)